# Why don't I need to pass in the signer or system_program account when using anchor ts?

Tags: anchor, program

I have the following Accounts struct in my program:

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct StartLottery<'info> {
    #[account(init, payer = user, space = 8 + 8 + 8 + 8)]
    pub lottery_state: Account<'info, LotteryState>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub user: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}
```

And make the following call to the respective endpoint from my client using anchor-ts:

```
const lotteryStateKeyPair = anchor.web3.Keypair.generate();

// Add your test here.
const tx = await program.methods
  .startLottery()
  .accounts({
    lotteryState: lotteryStateKeyPair.publicKey,
  })
  .signers([lotteryStateKeyPair])
  .rpc();
```

This transaction works and succeeds. My question is, why do I not need to pass the `user` account or the `system_program` account into the `.accounts({...})` method object and why do I not have to pass the `user` into the `.signers([...])` method array? Both the `system_program` and `user` are specified as dependencies in the `StartLottery` struct.

It seems that these fields are auto-populated. But why? What are the rules for when a signer or account field gets auto populated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the `.rpc()` method calls the `sendAndConfirm` ([src](https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/blob/47ff77f4df503b109e32a559daa209ade5f86487/ts/packages/anchor/src/program/namespace/rpc.ts#L29)) method on the *AnchorProvider* which uses *AnchorWallet* to sign the transaction before sending:

```
tx = await this.wallet.signTransaction(tx);
```

Found here: https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/blob/47ff77f4df503b109e32a559daa209ade5f86487/ts/packages/anchor/src/provider.ts#L156

Comment: What about the system program, why does that not need to be passed in?

Comment: Technically, you do need to pass it into the request, however, Anchor abstracts common/known accounts like system account and token program account and adds them under the hood for you.
If you'd like, you can use `.accountsStrict` method instead of `.accounts` and Anchor will force you to enter all necessary accounts including system program.

https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/blob/47ff77f4df503b109e32a559daa209ade5f86487/ts/packages/anchor/src/program/accounts-resolver.ts#L52

Comment: is there documentation for this or can you only find this out via reading the code?

Comment: Unfortunately, I couldn't find any Anchor docs which is why I pulled up the source.